# data getting overlaped in tableview cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I m parsing json data and assigning it in my table view cell.where in the first row of tableview cell .i m assigning a static data(green text).if i scroll my tableview the data assigned in first table view cell is getting overlaped in my 6th and 7th tableview cell.below is the screen shotand the code.could u guys help me out

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{

   cell.textLabel.text=@"Pollenprognosen";
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"se dagens pollenprognos";
    cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:([UIFont systemFontSize]-2)];

    return cell;
}
else
{
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.textLabel.text=[story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because the cell is reused. Try this code instead:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {

       cell.textLabel.text=@"Pollenprognosen";
        cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"se dagens pollenprognos";
        cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:([UIFont systemFontSize]-2)];
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {

    cell.textLabel.text=[story objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=nil;
cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        return cell;

    }
    }
```

Comment: No prob, glad to help a fellow SO:er.

Comment: dude i m facing the same problem of overlaping .but this time it comes to image.i ve posted it as a seperate question could u help me out

Answer (score 2):

Just make the `else` part as follows.

```
else
{
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d",indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"";

    return cell;
}
```